# Auto-sort after summarizing into a Mastersheet

Tags: excel, vba

For my occupation, I am currently making an Excel list which summarizes 6 lists into one master list, removes the header (A1:J7) and then sorts them by a criteria. In this case it would be the J(priority) and A(secondary) columns.

I have gotten it to the point where it merges the lists I need into one masterlist, yet it still leaves a bit of a space at the top (Header not being removed) and splits the lists themselves by headers.

The basis for my VBA would be --

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer
        On Error Resume Next
            Sheets(1).Select
                Worksheets.Add
                Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
                Sheets(2).Activate
                Range("A8").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A8")
        For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
                Sheets(J).Activate
                Range("A8").Select
                    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
                    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
                    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
        Next
End Sub
```

Now the difficulty I'm personally having, is how would I go about adding the function to remove the header, and then sort itself after the criteria which was named above.

I've looked online and scoured through Google, but I cannot find any help that not only answers but also explains the issue I'm having so that I know 'why' something has to be done in a specified order.

Comment: I don't think this bit is right: Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to elaborate? Im quite new to this all and am very interested in why that it would be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I've learned something today - I didn't know you could specify an offset with just (2) I would have written it as Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).offset(1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow what you're trying to do correctly:

```
  Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer
    dim targetcell as range
    Worksheets.Add before:=sheets(1)
    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
    set targetcell = sheets(1).range("a8") 'I think this is where you want to start
    with Sheets(2)
         .Range("A8").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetcell
         set targetcell = targetcell.offset(1,0) 'down one row
    end with
    For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(J).Range("A8").CurrentRegion
             ' Sheets(J).Range("A9:A" & .rows.count -8).copy  Destination:= targetcell
              'this should be:
               Sheets(J).Range("A9:A" & .rows.count -8).entirerow.copy  Destination:= targetcell
              'set targetcell = targetcell.offset(1,0)
               'should be replaced with 
               Set targetcell = Sheets("combined").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         end with
     Next J
     targetcell.currentregion.sort key1:=targetcell 'assume sort on column A
End Sub
```

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for the answer, time and patience you have shown thus far Harassed Dad, (twas away from all PC's for the weekend, so my apologies for the belated reply) 
In regards to the above mentioned. For some reason, its taken the list apart and only listed the A row whilst simultaniously removing all other information. Currently also reading up and fiddling about with it.

Comment: Good day to you Harassed Dad, that pretty much solved it for me :) Thanks alot, I learned quite a bit about everything with your help. If I may ask, as an extension if you would perhaps be able to?
Would there be a specific 'line' to add if I have varying numerals on the differed tables? Such as, lets say..Table 1 has 10, Table 2 has 15 etcetera. That Table 2 adds itself after the last cell from Table 1 was implemented in the master list itself?

Comment: Ah, I see the line, thank you very much Harassed Dad. You've been absolutely ace help. Much appreciated, thank you for the help and assistance.